# PC doesn't boot up first time, DRAM LED stays on. Second/third time booting up it all works fine

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

can anyone help me?

I recently purchased this RAM: https://www.pcdiga.com/gskill-ripjaws-v-ddr4-2133mhz-2x16gb-f4-2133c15d-32gvr

32GB RAM

but since then the PC never turns on the first time.
It only turns on after restarting or pressing the MemOK button several times
When the PC don't turn on the DRAM light is on

Specs are:
Asus z170-A motherboard
i5-6600K
GTX 970GPU
32gb RAM

If I shut down the computer and turn it back on again, there is no issue booting back up first time.
If I shut down the computer and leave it off for 45 minutes i have the same problem and PC doesn't boot up

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet... but have you tried reseating the RAM to make sure it's installed right?

You may have also gotten a faulty stick, you could try it with one DIMM at a time to see if either works normally. There's also the old memtest86+.

Comment: when i use one stick at a time only 16gb work without problem .. but when i use both i have this problem

Comment: Do you mean they both work by themselves? Or one works and one doesn't?

Comment: both work by themselves but togheter dont work :(

Comment: Ok. I at this point then I would check your motherboard's manual to 1) double check the RAM is compatible and 2) confirm you're using the right slots. Motherboards often require you use specific slots.